# Ksoap sending arguments and receiving results

Tags: android, web-services, ksoap2

I'm using KSoap within my Android application.
My application using Web Service for communicate with the server.
I have found a code sample of a KSoap wev service client.
In the sample, the client uses the following code for communication with the server -

```
Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
```

How do I pass arguments to the server?
How do I invoke the return value form the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use SoapObject.addProperty() to add argument and SoapSerializationEnvelope.getResponse() to get data returned by server.

Here is example: http://android-devblog.blogspot.com/2010/06/soap-on-android.html