# Android -- Passing a string to an already created webservice

Tags: java, android, ksoap2

I'm trying to create an Android app that will pass a string to this (http://www.yodaspeak.co.uk/webservice/yodatalk.php?wsdl) webservice and then receive the string that it returns. I know I should be using the ksoap2 library, but I am unsure as to how to go about even attempting to start going about this problem. I am very new to both Java and Android, so any code examples will not go unappreciated, but what I really need is some sort of explanation as to their use. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: See this post, may be its helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5052643/ksoap-sending-arguments-and-recieving-results

Answer (score 0):

The ksoap2-android project site has a wiki including a page with bunch of links on it as well as a mailing list and more documentation.

http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/

http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/wiki/Links

Answer (score 0):

I had written a (very) simple code example to demonstrate how to work with KSOAP2 in Android.

It can be found here: [KSOAP2 with Android](https://github.com/Sheikh-Aman/Android_Samples/tree/master/4.%20KSOAP_Demo)